# How to wrap 2 lists using bootstrap or css grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-grid

I have 2 lists of objects of different length I want to display in boxes. (list A and list B). I want the lists to be responsive for mobile and desktop. List 'B' should take only 1 column.

I've been able to get 2 lists to render but I'm not able to get list 'A' to expand the full width after list 'B' is done.

https://jsfiddle.net/heratyian/mcjenLpt/27/

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-6 col-md-8 col-lg-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A1
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A2
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A3
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A4
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A5
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A6
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A7
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A8
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A9
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A10
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A11
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box">
          A12
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 box">
          B1
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 box">
          B2
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 box">
          B3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a markdown table to show what I'm trying to do.

| . | . | . | . |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | A3 | **`B1`** |
| A4 | A5 | A6 | **`B2`** |
| A7 | A8 | A9 | A10 |
| A11 | A12 | A13 | A14 |

| . | . |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | **`B1`** |
| A2 | **`B2`** |
| A3 | A4 |
| A5 | A6 |

Is there a css grid property to tell list 'A' to take full available width? I'm using bootstrap grid, but am open to css-grid if needed.

Comment: thanks everyone. we got it working now https://popping.live

Answer (score 3):

You can get this using CSS grids.

The items must be direct child of the container. To get around this problem, you can chnage the HTML, or keep this intermediate level and hide it using display: contents;

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.list {
  display: contents;
}

.list div {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.B {
  grid-column-end: -1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.A {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="A">A1</div>
    <div class="A">A2</div>
    <div class="A">A3</div>
    <div class="A">A4</div>
    <div class="A">A5</div>
    <div class="A">A6</div>
    <div class="A">A7</div>
    <div class="A">A8</div>
    <div class="A">A9</div>
    <div class="A">A10</div>
    <div class="A">A11</div>
    <div class="A">A12</div>
    <div class="A">A13</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="B">B1</div>
    <div class="B">B2</div>
    <div class="B">B3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This plus @jottin answer make it complete. I'll try to award both a bounty for the team effort.

Comment: Much obliged heratyian!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to style your html that way. You are basically forcing two separate list contents (A and B) inside of each other based on available width. Content boxes (if you are using div's or li's) don't naturally flow this way, and to do this would require a css/javascript solution that will probably not be cross-browser friendly... just my opinion (sorry s.o.). There may be a flexbox or grid approach but definitely outside of the norm here. Good luck!

https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/

I stand corrected... @vals :-)
Here is how to make it responsive without media queries!

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(260px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 60px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer! I'm inspired by this website https://nomadlist.com I know it's possible, I just don't understand how.

Comment: Looks like I stand corrected. See vals answer... I wonder how this will translate responsively?

Comment: As a side note, CSS subgrids (that should be available in all browsers sometime in the future) provide a clearer solution to this problem

Comment: also `grid-auto-rows: 60px;` handles all rows (don't need to hardcode 16)

Answer (score 0):

```
      <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col--lg-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 box">
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box"></div>
         <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box"></div>
         </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12  box">
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box"></div>
         <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 box"></div>
         </div> 
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @lucifer. I believe this still has the issue that the first list (which is longer) wont expand after the second list is finished.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you actually want to creat it

Comment: Yes. I added bold to markdown table list B. Notice how row A fills in the empty space after list B is finished?